# Use existing tables on ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, model-view-controller

I have an existing database with a table named 'Unidades', and I'm tryin to give the AspNetUsers a single property Unidades:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{

    public Unidades Unidad { get; set; }
...
```

But, when I do this, ASP is trying to create a new table Unidades instead of using mine.
How can I tell ASP to use my existing table?

Thanks!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/models-data/creating-model-classes-with-the-entity-framework-cs

Comment: Thank u Waragi, but I already imported the database with DataBase First Approach. Thats why I have the Unidades class. But ASP is not using the existing table when on AspNetUser class.

Comment: so you want to use `Unidades` instead of `AspNetUsers`? And I am assuming you have all the columns in `Unidades` which are meant to be present in `AspNetUsers`

Comment: @Izzy, I want my AspNetUsers to have a 'Unidades' property

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Entity Framework 6, it would probably be easier to change your property from type Unidades to a virtual ICollection{Unidade} as seen here [https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entity-relationships.asp](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entity-relationships.aspx).

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public virtual ICollection<Unidad> Unidades { get; set; }    
    }
```

Then you could add a Table dataannotation on the Unidad class as seen here https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/table-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx

```
[Table("Unidades")]
public class Unidad {    
}
```